# How can MEF resolve dependencies of assemblies that don't live at the root of the application?

Tags: mvvm, mef, mefedmvvm

I have written my application to be a class library that is launched by a win32 MFC application.  Each of my views is a separate assembly that is located with the base class library that is located in a sub-directory of the hosted MFC application.

My question is, how can I get MEF to resolve the dependencies of my exported classes using the assemblies from this sub-directory instead of the root directory?

**This is what I want:**

> ```
> ParentFolder
>  myapp.exe
>  SubFolder
>      myMvvmWindow.dll
>      myMvvmSubWindow.dll
>      *Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll*
> ```

**This is what I have to have now:**

> ```
>   ParentFolder
>      myapp.exe
>      *Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll*
>      SubFolder
>          myMvvmWindow.dll
>          myMvvmSubWindow.dll
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this in your app.config file:

[Is it possible to set assembly probing path w/o app.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220349/is-it-possible-to-set-assembly-probing-path-w-o-app-config)

This is generally how I handle it.

Answer (score 0):

MEF will not handle this scenario for you, as it uses the CLR's normal assembly loading mechanisms to find dependencies.

However, you can easily work around this for a specific subdirectory by handling [AppDomain.AssebmlyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx).  If you check your sub folder for the assemblies that don't resolve in your main directory, you can load them yourself and make this function properly.